# AppDelegate protocol

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

i've implemented a transition methood in my app delegate file and from every where in the
code i want to call it in order to make nice and cool transitions. i call her like that

> [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] transFromMainToGalery];

for example.

the problem is that im getting warning which is ok (cause it already got approved by apple)
but i still want to fix it

the error:

> '-transFromMainToGalery' not found in the protocol

any ideas??

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your myAppDelegate.h file, make sure you have:

```
- (void) transFromMainToGalery;
```

Then cast the generic app delegate returned by the sharedApplication delegate to your specific app delegate class:

```
[ (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] transFromMainToGalery ];
```

Also include myAppDelegate.h in the header of your various other classes which use this message.

(substitute your app delegate class and file name for "myAppDelegate" as needed)

Answer (score 1):

Add the method signature to your AppDelegate's .h file and import that file in those .m files that you call it from.

Answer (score 0):

How about using UIApplication instead of UIApplicationDelegate.

```
@interface UIApplication (My)

-(void)myFunc;

@end
```

Implementing and calling are as below,

```
@implementation UIApplication (My)
-(void)myFunc {
}

...
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] myFunc];
...
```